# Присваивание значения срезу таблицы pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица вида:
[image: В индексе даты, для каждой даты есть стак различных видов доходов]

Необходимо для каждой даты уменьшить значения строки "Прочие доходы" на значение иных строк за рассматриваемую дату. Т.е. Прочие доходы - Налог на пибыль - НДФЛ - Акцизы - Налог на имущество - НДПИ.

Я попытался сделать так, но почему то этот вариант не работает:

```
cons.iloc[:,1:][cons.nalog == 'Прочие доходы'] = cons.iloc[:,1:][cons.nalog == 'Прочие доходы'] - cons[cons.nalog == 'Налог на прибыль'].iloc[:,1:] \
 - cons[cons.nalog == 'НДФЛ'].iloc[:,1:] - cons[cons.nalog == 'Акцизы'].iloc[:,1:] \
 - cons[cons.nalog == 'Налог на имущество'].iloc[:,1:]  - cons[cons.nalog == 'НДПИ'].iloc[:,1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Заработало вот так:

```
cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'Прочие доходы','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':] = cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'Прочие доходы','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':] - cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'Налог на прибыль','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':] - cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'НДФЛ','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':] - cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'Акцизы','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':] \
 - cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'Налог на имущество','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':]  - cons.loc[cons.nalog == 'НДПИ','РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ':]
```